# timer animation in monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, core-animation

I've noticed there's a lot of app that shows different timers on the screen and almost all of them are using nice animation while switching seconds and minutes (something like page with new number is flipped from top).
Is there more or less standard way to apply animation to my timer? is there any example showing how to animate timer in a nice looking way?

Comment: the effect I really meant below would be called flipdown timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the solution for this project:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-countdown/

jquery code is self-explanatory. it took under 40 minutes to port this to monotouch.

Comment: It's cute. You should post your port somewhere (e.g. github) as a sample.